# How to catch all output text in c

Tags: c, outputstream

This is my issue. I'm working on a unit testing class for a project in C. the unit testing class works great but one of methods it's testing calls a Method from an API to communicate with a piece of Hardware. because of the hardware's closed off software, there really is no way for me to allow it to run while I run my tests, and I shouldn't need to because of the black box nature of the tests.

These calls are simply char* messages being sent to the hardware and when running my test, I just get a lot of print outs of "Could not communicate with API". which I'm assuming is some sort of error checking on the API's part.

My question is, for the sake of a pretty output, is there anyway to catch, suppress, or check all text going to the terminal in this case.(Thats the output stream right? I'm fairly new to C)

Comment: See the book [Test-Driven Development for Embedded C](http://pragprog.com/book/jgade/test-driven-development-for-embedded-c).  It discusses extensively how to deal with such issues.

Answer (score 2):

You could also look at calling `freopen()` on stdout (or stderr) if you're linking in the code that generates those messages.  Unfortunately, you'll redirect all of the program's output.

It might be possible to keep a handle to the original stdout, create a pipe, call `freopen()` to redirect stdout to one side of the pipe, and have a thread read from the other side, filtering the output and passing "good" messages through to the original stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are running the program from a shell, in that case use `>` to send the output into a file. See [bash manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Otherwise I would need a bit more info.

Comment: note that `>` (or `1>`) only redirects stdout. If you also want to redirect stderr you'd also need to `2>`

Comment: @moooeeeep - Agreed - but you can do other wonderful things with bash. That is why I gave the link.

Comment: You could have linked better to [this article](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). The man-page is not quite verbose on this.

Comment: @moooeeeep - Probably better - but you can just lead sometimes. Hopefully the poster will gain an understanding on the benefits of knowing Bash

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly , assuming you are launching your application from some sort of shell (`bash` or otherwise) and are seeing `printf` going to the shell prompt. And your would like to save them to a file.

Well, the easy way to do that is with a `script` command.

You do the following.

```
 ~> script appOutputlog.log

 ~> ./app.exe
```

Once your done , either because app has finished or you have finished recording your log. U can use `Ctrl + D` or `Ctrl + C` to exit the script command. And you will have the `appOutputlog.log` file at local directory with all the logs that were printed on the command prompt at the shell.

2 other solution is to use `fopen` followed by `fprintf` instead of normal `printf`s.

3 another solution is to hook up your process to the `syslogd` running on your system. The is one of the most standard and production way to collect logs. `syslogd` is a system daemon process solely dedicated to record logs of different processes.